# Java regular expression: new line with forward slash in split

Tags: java

I want to capture below from regular expression.

```
  /

--//
```

or it can be

--//

I tried:

```
public static final String DELIMITER = "/\\n--//|-//";

ddl.addAll(..).split(DELIMITER)));
```

and combinations but nothing working.
I am using on Windows

Comment: Which OS are you using? Might be that Windows' newline is the problem. Windows uses `\r\n` for a newline. You can also use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to find the newline "character".

Comment: I am using Windows.. I updated my above question..

Comment: 1st: You say "or it can be --//" - your regular expression ends on "-//" - that's just one minus instead of two. 2nd: what is the result of `ddl.addAll(..)` ? 3rd: have you tried changing `\\n` to `\\r\\n` or `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as @JustABit proposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape so much. You are missing a second newline in your delimiter:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String text = "before" + "/" + newline + newline + "--//" + "after";
System.out.println(text);

String delimiter = "/" + newline + newline + "--//";
String[] parts = text.split(delimiter);
System.out.println(parts[0]); // prints "before"
System.out.println(parts[1]); // prints "after"
```

Comment: Thanks JustABit!!
As you suggested I was ablt to update as below and its working. Thanks Again!

        String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String string1 = "/" + newline + "--//";
        String string2 = "--//";

        final String DELIMITER = string1+"|"+string2;

        System.out.println("DELIMITER: "+DELIMITER);

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer as the correct answer by clicking on the checkmark symbol?